# Regex - Match a certain string and get the integer value of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex:

```
var example= Regex.Match(result, @"\b(Today is:)[\s:]*(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and then I convert

```
example= int.Parse(result.Groups[2].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

This works fine most of the time, however, I noticed that if I have extra string after Today is: for example,

`Today is (extra):`

My regex above fails for this case, because it also grabs "(extra)" and then goes to int.Parse, it fails. I want my regex to match when there's "Today is:", then it doesn't matter even if there are more strings, just get the string and convert into int value.

For example,
Today is: 100,000,000 -> convert and get int 100000000

Today is (abc123): 88,888 -> convert and get int 88888

Today is (Extra Text blah blah): 100,000 -> convert and get int 100000

Comment: Your regex pattern works with the 3 examples you gave? I don't see it working online: https://regexr.com/60s92

Comment: Can you be _very exact_ (in English rather than code) about the format of the string you are trying to parse? What are the expected rules it must obey?

Comment: It should be \b(Today is:)[\s:]*(.*)

Comment: `\: (\d.*)` this should do it; you're wanting digits after `:` right? If so, you can get the first groups value.

Comment: Format of the string always will be starting with "Today is" (case insensitive). So it will be always @"\b(Today is:)[\s:]* to start with.

Comment: It's going to be like, "Today is: 100,000" or it can be "Today is (extra): 33,333"

Comment: @davis but you only care about parsing the numbers right?

Comment: Correct. Not sure if there will be a colon after Today is, or could be a whitespace. So that's why I added [\s:]

Comment: @davis `\:? (\d.*)` should work.

Comment: By your examples, if it is always the end of the string, you could do `[0-9,]+$`

Comment: @Magnetron, can you provide a regex link for it

Comment: Yep, that's what happens when you mix multiple `*` (match zero or more) in succession. it gets hard to envisage what matches. Simplify your life, use a modification of the regex from your last question - `Today is\D+(?<n>[0-9,]+)` - if you want digits, specify so, rather than using `.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change a bit your regex like this:

```regex
\bToday is\b.*?\s*:\s*([\d,\.]+)
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/jPb6Pa/1

Explanation:

- `\bToday is\b` for searching "*Today is*" and not "*Blablatoday isn't*" or something like that.
- `.*?` searches anything after "*Today is*" but in an ungready way.
- `\s*:\s*` searches for the ":" char with or without spaces around.
- The capturing group n°1 `([\d,\.]+)` will search for digits, points and commas, at least one character. It could be improved as a single comma or point would be wrong. But it does the job for the moment.

Comment: Can we make the ":" optional? so that if Today is doesn't have a colon just get the value. If it has it then also get the value

Comment: @davis, yes, if you want to have an optional `:` then just add a question mark after it. This leads to `bToday is\b.*?\s*:?\s*([\d,\.]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
\bToday\s+is\b(?:.*?\([^()]*\))?.*?\b(\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PApfYl/1). Parse the `match.Groups[1].Value`.

*Details*:

- `\bToday\s+is\b` - `Today is` as whole words with any one or more whitespaces in between
- `(?:.*?\([^()]*\))?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible followed with a `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: a number pattern.